# Mysql connection Tomcat 7 on Openshift

Tags: mysql, tomcat7, openshift

I deployed application on openshift server (tomcat, mysql) but I can't connect with my db (I use phpmyadmin to create db and tables). On my localhost everythings work well. Here is my persistence:

```
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence   http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
<persistence-unit name="eshopPU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
<provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
<class>foo.domain.Catalog</class>
<exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
<properties>
  <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="mysql://$OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST:$OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PORT/katalog"/>
  <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="dyfghd"/>
  <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
  <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="abyrewef"/>
  <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="create-tables"/>
</properties>
</persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

server logs:
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'katalogDAO': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: foo.repositories.KatalogRepository foo.repositories.KatalogDAO.katalogRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'katalogRepository': Injection of persistence dependencies failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.2.v20111125-r10461): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

I don't know what is wrong. Thanks for help.

Comment: Are you using the JBoss EWS 2.0 cartridge?  If so, there's a preconfigured DS in your repo's .openshift/config/context.xml file with the following: 

   <Resource name="jdbc/MysqlDS"
              url="jdbc:mysql://${OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST}:${OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PORT}/${OPENSHIFT_APP_NAME}"
              driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
              username="${OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_USERNAME}"
              password="${OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PASSWORD}"
              auth="Container"
              type="javax.sql.DataSource"
...
              />

Comment: sorry for the formatting.  NOTE the dbname is your $appName, and the env variables for your db user creds.

Comment: I have jboss as 7 app, myapp-tjava.rhcloud.com, I am using this in my context.xml, and a blank screen appears on the rhcloud server:    <Resource name="connpool" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
              maxActive="100" maxIdle="30" maxWait="10000"
              username="adminFbzQ2yE" password="${OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PASSWORD}" driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
              url="jdbc:mysql://${OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST}:${OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PORT}/${OPENSHIFT_APP_NAME}"/> Locally I see an exception (logical), but the other resources like form.html are working.

Comment: When I replace the openshift vars locally, it is working, I use Tomcat

Comment: Why does it not work with Jboss AS 7 and only with Jboss Ews 2.0 to use context.xml? Can you change that? There is a good thread https://community.jboss.org/message/620652?_sscc=t, however it does not treat the mysql resource element

Comment: Solved using the resource tag to connect to mysql on openshift with tomcat 7, here an instruction to read https://www.google.de/search?q=context.xml+openshift+jboss+ews&oq=context.xml+openshift+jboss+ews&aqs=chrome..69i57.10239j0j4&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I solved the issue. In persistance.xml and spring configuration file I inserted the user and password (properties) the same like I had in my db connection on openshift. In url propertie I put :

```
value="jdbc:mysql://${OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST}:${OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PORT}/${OPENSHIFT_APP_NAME}"
```

and works fine (I use tomcat 7 and mysql 5.1, app based on spring 3 and thymeleaf).

Comment: I'm also trying to deploy my webapp based on Tomcat and MySQL (with Spring and Hibernate). I'm having trouble using the default datasource provided by OpenShift because I already have my own configuration of files and folders. My app is running at my Localhost. In the JBoss log also shows this exception: `...the JDBC driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.` Can you give me some guidelines on how to configure my project in order to make use of the default DS?